# Running an ODEProblem until given a signal

Tags: callback, julia, simulation, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

Is it possible for the timespan of an `ODEProblem` to be open-ended, i.e. for the problem to run until given an external signal (possibly via a discrete callback with an appropriate condition)? Intuitively, this would mean giving something like `tspan = (0.0, Inf)`, although I'm not sure if that is allowed and can't seem to find anything in the [documentation](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/index.html). TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `tspan = (0.0, Inf)`. Of course, if you do this, you'll want to make sure you setup [a terminating event like in this example](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_functions/#Example-2:-Terminating-an-Integration) so that it doesn't run forever, or you can use the [integrator interface](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/integrator/) to control the steps and stop whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you, I'm always glad when Julia works like I expect it to. :)